# How do I connect an existing SQLite database to an ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, expandablelistview

I've been trying to prepare custom `Views` to display SQLite database entries during a whole week without success.

I already tried the default list and Room Persistence Library approaches and even considered a JSON/GSON alternative, but to populate lists within lists with basic text strings seemed to be the easiest attempt meanwhile.

Basically, now I'm trying to mix two samples at once:

- [one about SQLite](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html);
- [other about ExpandableListViews](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/).

I've been able to add data from my database and to mix them up to some extent, but I ain't getting how to connect the database fields to the custom `Views` on both levels of the list.

After I reached the `ExpandableListView` on the `MainActivity.java`, I got lost and I think the code may have some duplicated methods, maybe a confusion between `dataAdapter` and the use of `listAdapter` and the `HashMap<String, List<String>>()` is probably wrong, but I don't have a clue about how to solve issues like these as of now, so, I ask for some help please to handle this situation.

Comment: use `android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I must I wasn't aware about this. I guess it'd replace the `SimpleCursorAdapter`, right? I'm going to try this approach now and I update the question code if I stuck at another point.

Comment: yes its replacement for `SimpleCursorAdapter` when used in `ExpandableListView` - all you need to do is to implement `getChildrenCursor()` method for it to work

Comment: Yes, it feels like a perfect fit until now. I've just changed the `SimpleCursorAdapter` and separated the previous column into group and child columns, but I'm still confused about how to handle the `getChildrenCursror()` method (first time dealing with both SQLite and ExpandableListView).

Comment: `getChildrenCursor` takes `Cursor groupCursor` as a parameter - use it - if you dont know its content call for testing purposes `DatabaseUtils#dumpCurrentRow` method to see it on the `logcat`

Comment: I'll try to restart the code mix from scratch trying to adopt your suggestion as far as I'm able. If something new comes up, I update here.

Comment: see https://pastebin.com/raw/4ZKWgSr1

Comment: I'm still getting in the loop, but many aspect of the code is clearer now. A question I have is about the hardcoded database. Testing other samples, even when I reached a working code, this written table has been the only data retrieved and my stored database has been ignored. Do you know what could cause something like that?

Comment: No problem. I still need to figure out many things about this subject. Really first time trying to deal with Android/SQLite combo and it has been driven me crazy and curious at the same time.

Comment: the code i gave you is the most simple form i think, so you can use it as a starter - also take a look into `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor` and `DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRow` - they saved my life (or at least hours of testing) couples of time - for example uncomment `dumpCurrentRow` inside `getChildrenCursor` to see the cursor content

Comment: I'm Brazilian, so, if you'd like some tips, I can answer you some questions and we can practice by chat if you like too. I've been answering some questions about Portuguese language on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/profile/Jorge-Am%C3%A9rico-Vargas-Freitas) as well. Do you speak any Latin language or are used to the grammatical basis of it?

Comment: yes i speak latin language so it should not be much problem - btw do you know any good flash cards for [anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) app ?

Comment: Very useful tip. I'm looking for a way to integrate the three pieces now and still many red flags to correct. But as soons as the code is clean and runable, I'll take a look at that. I think I've seen some samples of it in use while reading some tutorials lately.

Comment: That's a good starting point. From speaking Portuguese and Spanish, it was easier to understand French with some study and Italian just by talking online. So, I guess the opposite way might be valid at least in a textual level. When learning a language, I like to get used to the verbal conjugation (in Portuguese, pretérito perfeito, presente and futuro do presente along with Eu and Você - a kind of third-conjugation second person - are the most useful for a start). And actually I wasn't even aware about this app. I reading about it right now in fact.

Comment: I've just discovered that the original code about which I questioned was atually almost working. It seems I ignored a law: >The Cursor must include a column named _id or this class will not work. Now with the app running will be easier to implement you tips. I noticed it may be better to have different layout for ieach item brought from the database and that my assets folder database is being ignored since the code only retrives the `insertSome`. I'm going to rest a little bit because it's been long hours. Later I'm paying more attention to the code and the appl. Muito obrigado pela paciência!

Comment: sure you can use a custom (and very complex) `BaseExpandableListAdapter` but it is a lot easier to use `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` - just 10 or so lines of code

Comment: Definitely, my friend. It's been a week overthinking this. I've been trying to figure out how to merge the samples, but I think they aren't easily compatible. I'm going to work from `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` from now on. Way easier like you've said. Actually, I still have a question: how to use just a premade database instead of writting one from strings in an activity? I've been able to retrive a line from a DB Browser database, but since I've been trying custom adapter, my assets folder database is always ignored. I realize all of them are creating it rather than picking from mine.

Comment: see https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: I don't know where some of our comments went to, but anyway: it's solved! [`SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.html) and [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) do magic when we get it and you've been precise to guide me to see beyond. Now, I'll just figure how to grab subitems from more than one column for each item in order so that I can create a database. Please, do answer refering a summary of your tips so as I can close this question otherwise I do that as myself referring to them.

Comment: great it works now... i give you the honor to self answer ;-)

Comment: Are you sure? I'd really like to upvote and close this issue following your tips. So, I'd be honored if you'd did so. ;)

Comment: Ok then. I'm leaving a summary of your tips and I'm uploading the source code to GitHub as soon as it's done and bringing here to this question if possible. Thanks again for the tips and advices: they meant a lot! Now about the flashcards, I ain't aware about good ones because I've never tried them, but I'll have a a look and inform you. Please, start a chat with me here (because I can't) or on another network like Twitter, for instance, and I feed you with good content in Portuguese everyonce in a while and send you a selection of flashcards I find good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are trying to fetch data from a prepopulated SQLite database into an [`ExpandableListView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), you can simply use [this sample code](https://github.com/JorgeAmVF/android-prepopulated-sqlite-database) I created after asking this question here and there.

You'd just need to replace [the database in this project](https://github.com/JorgeAmVF/prepopulated-sqlite-database/tree/master/app/src/main/assets/databases) by yours and refactor [the respective fields to match your database name, table and items](https://github.com/JorgeAmVF/prepopulated-sqlite-database/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jorgeamvf/prepopulatedsqlitedatabase/Database.java) so as it fits your needs.

Basically, with a [`SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.html), you'll be able to select two levels of data (group and child) from your database and [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) will let you to load it from a preexisting file put inside the assets folder (/app/src/main/assets/databases/).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [psikink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) support, I've been able to find a workaround for this issue.

Actually, during a whole week I've been looking for approaches over simple samples of [`ListViews`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) and [`ExpandableListView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) with custom adapters, but as soon as I was able to catch the mindset of the advices provided, it was way easier to deal with this situation.

The turning point was to know about [`SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.html) and to pay more attention to [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) methodology.

As soon as the code is ready, I'll upload it to my [GitHub profile](https://github.com/JorgeAmVF) and I'll try to bring it here as well if possible.

As of now, this [piece of code](https://pastebin.com/raw/4ZKWgSr1) might be helpful, I guess.

Thanks Stack Overflow and [psikink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) for the help!

Comment: [Here is a better explanation and the sample code I promissed in the past.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50784315/6398434)